# Detecting first/second/third person pronouns

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger

I'm looking for a way to detect whether a personal pronoun is first person (I), second person (you) or third person (they). The code is looking to see if someone is talking about themselves, but has some other applications too.

A python library would be fantastic, but not necessary. nltk.pos_tag will tell me what are personal pronouns, but I can't seem to get more information than that.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be trivial to write yourself. As you said, NLTK can give you all pronouns, and you can easily write a function to return a detailed morphological analysis by simple string matching. Just pass the things tagged as pronouns to said function.

Pronouns are so-called "closed class" words, i.e. there's a finite (and small) amount of them. There is no way (in the English language) to generate *new* pronouns. Nouns, on the other hand, are "open class" i.e. you can can generate new nouns (compound nouns, such as "beaver teeth" or what have you.)

So you just use something like `f(x) = if x == "I" || x == "me" || x == "my" then return "1st. person singular"` ... or some such. Obviously you would not want to return a string, but something more informative, such as an object with fields `number` and `person`, and possibly `possessive` or even `case`.

One more thing: since NLTK is a statistical tagger, it will sometimes tag as pronouns words that simply aren't. In this case you should be prepared to return an error condition.